# What's the name of this curve?

Tags: curves

Sorry for the very beginner question but I just can't find the name or formula of [such a curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOJX3.png). It's probably simple but Math is not my strongest field.

It's like a sinusoidal curve but it starts and end steeps while the center part is mort smooth.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I found Arccos(1-x) fits my need! Solved and thanks a lot to ones that answered me

Comment: An odd polynomial, like $y=x^3$, gives that shape.

Comment: I have multiple questions to clarify.
The typical method is to y on the vertical axis and x on the horizontal axis.  Did you mean to reverse them?
On the vertical lines does it touch the vertical lines?  Get closer and closer to either vertical mine, but never actually cross?  This would be called an asymptote which means the function increases or decreases forever
Does this graph repeat?  If so, how long does it take from one complete cycle to the next?

Comment: $x = tan( y - 1) + c$ is another possible equation for your graph.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll check it out asap
As for your questions, my bad I just switch x and y. It does not repeat itself and is limited to the x (y on my graph) range. It does not touch the vertical lines.

Sorry for my amateurism